# If statement using every array key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How may I get the following but without manually writing each key? I want the if statement to include every `colors` key.

```
if (colors[0].val.join() === colors[colors[0].next].orig.join() &&
    colors[1].val.join() === colors[colors[1].next].orig.join() &&
    colors[2].val.join() === colors[colors[2].next].orig.join() &&
    colors[3].val.join() === colors[colors[3].next].orig.join() &&
    colors[4].val.join() === colors[colors[4].next].orig.join())
{ }
```

All I can come up with is:

```
colors.forEach(function(k, i) {
    colors[i].val.join() === colors[colors[i].next].orig.join();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [.every() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
if (colors.every(function(el) { return el.val.join() === colors[el.next].orig.join(); })) {
    // do something
}
```

It will work on every browser, besides IE < 9.

If you need older IE support, polyfill the method (a polyfill is available on the MDN documentation)

Comment: Ah, I see; I hadn't seen the property listed in the original question (or I'd glossed over it somehow).